# Perturbational approach to study a Non linear PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, perturbation-theory

Lets suppose I have $\mathcal{\hat{H}}\psi=(\mathcal{\hat{H}}_0+\lambda \hat{V})\psi=0$ where $\hat{V}$ is some -non linear - perturbation to $\mathcal{\hat{H}}_0$ controlled by the parameter $\lambda$ and $\mathcal{\hat{H}}_0 $ is a linear operator. Moreover, $\mathcal{\hat{H}}_0 $ is the heat operator:

\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{\hat{H}}_0 = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2 }
\end{equation*}
and the perturbation is:
\begin{equation}
\hat{V}\psi=\left(\frac{\partial^2\psi }{\partial x^2}\right)^2
\end{equation}

I would like to study this problem with the following initial-boundary conditions:
\begin{equation*}
\displaystyle
    \left\{\begin{array}{l}
    \psi(x,t) \rightarrow e^x\quad\textrm{if}\quad x\rightarrow \infty
    \\ \\  \displaystyle
    \psi(x,t) \rightarrow 0\quad\textrm{if}\quad x\rightarrow 0
    \\ \\  \displaystyle
    \psi(x,t)= e^{max(x,0)}-1 \quad\textrm{if}\quad t= 0   
    \end{array}\right.
\end{equation*}

If $\psi(x,t)$ is an analytical function of $\lambda$ then it can be written as:
\begin{equation}
\psi=\psi_0+\lambda\psi_1+...+\lambda^n\psi_n\,.
\label{psi-lambda-expansion}
\end{equation}

This summation will be studied up to $n=N$. Using the above eq. we can write:
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{\hat{H}}\psi=\mathcal{\hat{H}}_0\psi_0 +\lambda(\mathcal{\hat{H}}_0\psi_1+\hat{V}\psi_0)+O(\lambda^2)\,.
\end{equation*}
From above it follows that $\mathcal{\hat{H}}\psi=0$,  $\forall\lambda$ if and only if  every coefficient in the polynomial expansion vanishes. Note that now the term $\hat{V}\psi_0$ could be analytically known if I define proper initial-boundary conditions to $\mathcal{\hat{H}_0}$. Indeed, I can easily solve the equation $\mathcal{\hat{H}_0}\psi_0=0$.

My problem is how to introduce consistent initial-boundary conditions to $\psi_i$. In my first try I though that maybe if I go with:
\begin{equation*}
\displaystyle
    \left\{\begin{array}{l}
    \psi_i(x,t) \rightarrow \frac{1}{(N+1)\lambda^i}e^x\quad\textrm{if}\quad x\rightarrow \infty
    \\ \\  \displaystyle
    \psi_i(x,t) \rightarrow 0\quad\textrm{if}\quad x\rightarrow 0
    \\ \\  \displaystyle
    \psi_i(x,t)=\frac{1}{(N+1)\lambda^i} e^{max(x,0)}-1 \quad\textrm{if}\quad t= 0  
    \end{array}\right.
\end{equation*}

the summation of the boundary conditions for each $\psi_i$ will sum up to the required conditions to $\psi$ but this will not work because then the solution for each $\psi_i$ will depend upon $1/\lambda^i$ and $\psi$ will not have a Taylor expansion on $\lambda$. How can I define consistent boundary-initial conditions effectively solve this problem at least at order $\lambda$?.

Comment: What sort of dependence does $V$ have on $x$ and $t$? Is it negligible on the boundaries where you're fixing initial conditions?

Comment: I suspect, but am not sure, that fixing boundary conditions for each $\psi_i$ is fixing too many degrees of freedom, and that you need to instead solve the perturbation equations and then apply the boundary condition to just the total $\psi$.

Comment: @jwimberley. I already edited the post with the additional information you required.

Comment: Given that V has the same form as the second term in $H_0$, you can solve this exactly for $\psi$ and then expand it and its boundary conditions. That could be the easiest way to figure out what they are like, and hopefully learn things that could generalize to cases where you can't solve exactly.

Comment: @jwimberley Can you give me a more detailed explenation how should I be able to solve  this eqn exactly for $\psi$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @FedericoVega Sorry, I misinterpreted what $\partial^2_{x^2}$ meant and thought it was the same non-linear operator that's in $V$.

Comment: @jwimberley sorry, I edited the post again. The notation was not clear. Anyway it is true that the second derivative appears in both terms.